URL API behaves differently in Edge
When I'm trying to use native URL API for validation purposes, surprisingly, Edge browser behaves differently. So the input of:


const myUrlString = "abfss://myprojectname/filename.csv";
const myUrl = new URL(myUrlString);
console.log(myUrl);



Note: abfss:// is Microsoft's Azure file storage protocol.
Chrome returns:
{
  "hash": "",
  "host": "myprojectname",
  "hostname": "myprojectname",
  "href": "abfss://myprojectname/filename.csv",
  "origin": "null",
  "password": "",
  "pathname": "/filename.csv",
  "port": "",
  "protocol": "abfss:",
  "search": "",
  "username: "",
  ...
}

Edge returns:
{
    "hash": "",
    "host": "",
    "hostname": "",
    "href": "abfss://myprojectname/filename.csv",
    "origin": "null",
    "password": "",
    "pathname": "//myprojectname/filename.csv",
    "port": "",
    "protocol": "abfss:",
    "search": "",
    "username": "",
    ...
}

Notice host and hostname being empty strings.
For some reason, it doesn't parse any URLs with non-http(s) protocol.
Does anyone know how to solve this to have uniform behavior across browsers?



const myUrlString = "abfss://myprojectname/filename.csv";
const myUrl = new URL(myUrlString);
console.log(myUrl);



{
  "hash": "",
  "host": "myprojectname",
  "hostname": "myprojectname",
  "href": "abfss://myprojectname/filename.csv",
  "origin": "null",
  "password": "",
  "pathname": "/filename.csv",
  "port": "",
  "protocol": "abfss:",
  "search": "",
  "username: "",
  ...
}


I can reproduce this issue on Edge Stable and Edge Beta, but it works fine on Edge Dev and Edge Canary.
Anyway, it looks like a regression issue, and I suggest you report this problem to the Edge Dev Team by sending feedback. You can send feedback in Microsoft Edge at ··· menu --> Help and feedback --> Send feedback.
And the workaround is to use Dev and Canary for the time being.

For the record, my version is 131.0.2903.86 (Official build) (x86_64)
